# swiftUI drag and drop dulicate image on screen

Tags: swiftui

I am new to swiftui and have been trying create a horizontal image bar (that already works), but with it I want to be able to drag and drop those images unto the screen (basically copy them), but not on a grid (so freely moving around).

I have been looking at code, but all of them seems to be used on Lists, and I don't use a list.

This is the code I am using, any advise would be helpfull.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Instrument: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let image: String
}

struct StageView: View {
    @State private var instruments = [
        Instrument(name: "Drums", image: "drums"),
        Instrument(name: "Percussion", image: "drums"),
        Instrument(name: "Synthesizer", image: "synthesizer"),
        Instrument(name: "Piano", image: "piano"),
        Instrument(name: "El-Guitar", image: "el-git"),
        Instrument(name: "Acc-Guitar", image: "acc-guitar"),
        Instrument(name: "Bass-Guitar", image: "drums"),
        Instrument(name: "Trumpet", image: "trumpet"),
        Instrument(name: "Trombone", image: "trombone"),
        Instrument(name: "Violin", image: "violin"),
        Instrument(name: "Flute", image: "flute"),
        Instrument(name: "Harp", image: "harp"),
        Instrument(name: "Oboe", image: "oboe"),
        Instrument(name: "Saxophone", image: "saxophone"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(spacing: 5) {
                    ForEach(instruments) { instrument in
                        RectangleView(label: instrument.name, image: instrument.image)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }.frame(height: 70)
            Divider()
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Text("The content of the Home view")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct RectangleView: View {
    @State var label: String
    @State var image: String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 1)
                    .frame(width: 140, height: 70)
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(label)
                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                    .background(Color.white)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StageView()
        .previewInterfaceOrientation(.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

This is the view with the images at the top, and below it should drop the images
[image]

Comment: You want drag one of Image and drop on white area, after drop they must stay in same location or change the position to top-left?

Comment: @swiftPunk, thanks for your reply. They should be both, the copied image should be on the white area (basically as copy of the top image). And top images should remain, so they can be copied more if needed.

Comment: It is doable projects but not easy one! There is 2 projects backed together, 1 drag and drop, 2. replacing the dropped image.

Comment: are there any examples on how to approach this?

Comment: I do not think so, these things are assets of any commercial apps like photoshop or LogicPro, ... . May you code for yourself or I dot know find an acceptable API for your project. I can do this work, but it would require lots of coding and testing and so many hours, I cannot answer you here right now because it is not easy one.